# how can l add a (') in a cell below before entering characters in it so that excel does not read the first character ("@") as a formula

Tags: excel, vba

How can I add a `'` in a cell below before entering characters in it so that Excel does not read the first character (`@`) as a formula in VBA?

I am using a bar code scanner but it is producing special characters on the spread sheet when I scan a bar code, Excel automatically reads the first letter of the characters as a formula. The character is `@`.

[image]

Comment: Set up the scanner to send `'` before the barcode data. Or format the cells as Text before scanning.

Comment: l formatted the whole column thats all l wanted thank you very Sir